# What Is Parameterized Cursor and and which case we need to use this?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I want to know about parameterized cursor which belongs to PLSQL, So what is parameterized cursor ...
1). When and how we can use this cursor type?.
2). At which point of view we can use a parameterized cursor, Means when we need to use it?

Answer (score 4):

It is a cursor that uses a parameter.

Use it whenever necessary; if cursor doesn't need a parameter, then don't use it (and vice versa). One of possible uses would be a nested cursor loop. Based on Scott's schema, I'm first fetching departments (in a cursor FOR loop), and then loop through all employees (using the explicit cursor) that belong to that department which is passed as a parameter:

```
SQL>   declare
  2    cursor c1 (par_deptno in number) is --> PAR_DEPTNO is cursor's parameter
  3      select ename
  4      from emp
  5      where deptno = par_deptno;
  6    c1r c1%rowtype;
  7  begin
  8    for cur_d in (select deptno, dname from dept) loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line('Dept. ' || cur_d.dname);
 10      dbms_output.put_line('  List of Employees:');
 11
 12      open c1 (cur_d.deptno);           --> when opening the cursor, pass parameter's value
 13      loop
 14        fetch c1 into c1r;
 15        exit when c1%notfound;
 16
 17        dbms_output.put_line('  - ' || c1r.ename);
 18      end loop;
 19      close c1;
 20    end loop;
 21  end;
 22  /
Dept. ACCOUNTING
List of Employees:
- CLARK
- KING
- MILLER
Dept. RESEARCH
List of Employees:
- SMITH
- JONES
- SCOTT
- ADAMS
- FORD
Dept. SALES
List of Employees:
- ALLEN
- WARD
- MARTIN
- BLAKE
- TURNER
- JAMES
Dept. OPERATIONS
List of Employees:

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

More info in documentation ([Explicit cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/explicit_cursor.htm#LNPLS01313)).